# How to combine 2 SQL statements into one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 SQL statements to look up successful transactions and failed transactions.

```
SELECT COUNT (code_reseller) as trx_success, kode_reseller
FROM transaksi
where status = '20' AND CAST (date_entri AS DATE) = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) 
group by code_reseller
ORDER BY trx_success DESC
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT (code_reseller) as trx_fail, kode_reseller
FROM transaksi
where status > '20' AND CAST (date_entri AS DATE) = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) 
group by code_reseller
ORDER BY trx_fail DESC
```

How to combine into one table with 3 columns result with code_reseller, trx_success and trx_fail?

Comment: Probably `union all`

Comment: Have a sample for that?

Comment: Um..... google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation and combine the queries:

```sql
SELECT
    kode_reseller,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_success,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status > '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_fail
FROM transaksi
WHERE
    CAST(date_entri AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
GROUP BY
    kode_reseller;
```

The strategy here is to move the filtering on the `status` column which previously appeared in the two `WHERE` clauses into the conditional counts in the `SELECT` clause.  The restriction on `date_entri` can stay there, since both queries have it.

Comment: Had a typo, please reload your page.

Comment: `CAST AS DATE` probably better written as a half-open date interval

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Dale k, you can do it like this.

You cannot add order by inside, so create an alias table and give order by condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT (code_reseller) as trx_success, kode_reseller
    FROM transaksi
    WHERE status = '20' AND CAST (date_entri AS DATE) = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    GROUP BY code_reseller

    UNION ALL

    SELECT COUNT (code_reseller) as trx_fail, kode_reseller
    FROM transaksi
    WHERE status > '20' AND CAST (date_entri AS DATE) = CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    GROUP BY code_reseller
 ) a
 ORDER BY a.trx_success DESC --here we get first select query table' column name and datatype and no of column will be same required in union/union all
```